# How does RabbitMQ publisher confirms work?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have gone through rabbitmq documentation, 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms

> Using standard AMQP 0-9-1, the only way to guarantee that a message
>   isn't lost is by using transactions -- make the channel transactional
>   then for each message or set of messages publish, commit. **In this
>   case, transactions are unnecessarily heavyweight and decrease
>   throughput by a factor of 250. To remedy this, a confirmation
>   mechanism was introduced. It mimics the consumer acknowledgements
>   mechanism already present in the protocol**.
>
> To enable confirms, a client sends the confirm.select method.
>   Depending on whether no-wait was set or not, the broker may respond
>   with a confirm.select-ok. Once the confirm.select method is used on a
>   channel, it is said to be in confirm mode. A transactional channel
>   cannot be put into confirm mode and once a channel is in confirm mode,
>   it cannot be made transactional.

Currently I am using RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend of spring-rabbit library to send message.
I am using transactional channel to publish messages to rabbitmq, As per the document its slower and I can can improve the throughput by using publisher-confirm.

But I am not much clear about it.

If I want to enable confirm then what are changes required and how do I handle exception?
What will be my retrial mechanism?
Does this publisher confirm work in asynchronous way? 
And does transaction work in synchronously?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using publisher confirms will not improve performance significantly over transactions if you wait for the confirm for each individual send. They help significantly if you send many messages and wait for the confirms later.

Transactions are synchronous. Confirms are completely asynchronous.

See [Confirms and Returns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#template-confirms).

When you enable confirms, you provide a callback to the template which will be called when the confirm is received. You add correlation data to the send, which is provided in the callback so you can determine which send this confirm is for. Furthermore, the correlation data (in recent versions) provides a `Future<?>` which you can wait on to receive the confirm in a synchronous manner.

That's where you would handle any exception(s).

I hope that helps.

There is a confirms and returns sample Spring Boot application in the [samples repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/spring-rabbit-confirms-returns) but it was created before the future was added to the `CorrelationData`. That [will be fixed soon](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/issues/56).

The correlation data can contain the original message, enabling retry.

Comment: Thank you Gary, You have cleared my doubts. 
For me confirmation in later time is fine, 
the correlated data will work for re-send.

But will it maintain ordering, lets say m5 is failed to be published in RMQ and m6, m7 successful, So any consumer listening to the RMQ, will lost the ordering. Please correct me . Or I need to catch the exception and start again from m5 and continue publishing to RMQ by repeating the later successful message m6, m7 ... by maintaining all the messages in buffer until I get the confirmation till that point, Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: The final , if my RMQ consumer system depends on ordering, Is there a way to use publisher confirm to publish message to RMQ?

Comment: There can be no ordering guarantees; most likely if m5 fails, m6 and m7 will too, but it's certainly possible that m6 and m7 could succeed. If ordering is required, then I think transactions are the only option. Furthermore, to ensure ordering, you should do all sends within the scope of a `template.invoke()` operation (unless you only have one thread sending messages). See [Scoped Operations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#scoped-operations).